# Razor Pages with EF Core in ASP.NET Core - Update Related Data - 7 of 8 with c#

Tags: c#, razor-pages

I am an experienced visual basic programmer trying to learn Visual Studio with Razor Pages. I've followed the tutorial and can't get past an error.  When I add the courses taught by the instructor (the following code) and hit save I get an error

```
NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

ContosoUniversity.Pages.Instructors.Pages_Instructors_Edit.<ExecuteAsync>b__19_0() in Edit.cshtml
  foreach (var course in Model.AssignedCourseDataList)
```

Here is my code

```
 </div> <div class="form-group">
  <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
   <<tr>
      @{
       int cnt = 0;
       foreach (var course in Model.AssignedCourseDataList)
       {
         if (cnt++ % 3 == 0)
         {
          @:</tr><tr>
         }
         @:<td>

        <input type="checkbox"
          name="selectedCourses"
          value="@course.CourseID"
          @(Html.Raw(course.Assigned ? "checked=\"checked\"" : "")) />
          @course.CourseID @:  @course.Title
          @:</td>
         }
         @:</tr>
       }
    </table>
 </div>
```

But I found if I remove the office location for the instructor which precedes course  assignment (the following code) the error goes away.  The same problem occurs on the create instructors page.  I just can't figure out why one or the other works but not both at the same time.  I'd appreciate some help very much

```
  <div class="form-group">
      <label asp-for="Instructor.OfficeAssignment.Location" class="control-label"></label>
      <input asp-for="Instructor.OfficeAssignment.Location" class="form-control" />
      <span asp-validation-for="Instructor.OfficeAssignment.Location" class="text-danger" />
  </div>
```

Comment: Most likely, you have forgotten to instantiate the `AssignedCourseDataList` in the `OnPostAsync` handler in the `EditModel`. I believe this is done by calling the `PopulateAssignedCourseData` method within the handler body.

Comment: i will look for this .thanks

Comment: here is my onpostasync in editmodel. i'm coping the code the tutorial..my hands don't work well so i use speech.sorry. why does it work if officeassignment is removed?z

Comment: }
                UpdateInstructorCourses(_context, selectedCourses, instructorToUpdate);
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
                return RedirectToPage("./Index");
            }
            UpdateInstructorCourses(_context, selectedCourses, instructorToUpdate);
            PopulateAssignedCourseData(_context, instructorToUpdate);
            return Page();

Comment: i guess can't do that

Comment: You were right about the cause of the error.  I'm getting better at the debugger.  I still can't find Y if I remove to the code before that the error goes away

Comment: https://github.com/aspnet/Docs/issues/10449

Answer (score 0):

If this problem is still troubling you, It's probably because you haven't copied the models correctly, therefore re-check your models ,( 5 of 8).

You can try inputting this inside OnPostAsync method to get more information on it,

```
if (!ModelState.IsValid)
{
   return BadRequest(ModelState);
}
```

Comment: [StringRange(AllowableValues = new[] { "M", "F" }, ErrorMessage = "Gender must be either 'M' or 'F'.")]  
        public string TransType { get; set; }

Comment: Take Trans Type and Gender off and Drop the database and redo the migration process again, It's probably because those data are missing while posting.